# Corda Nodes in Headless Mode

Tags: corda

is there some way to run the corda samples in headless mode in both linux and microsoft? the individual nodes such as Bank of Corda, Notary, etc are popping. When the command line/dialog are closed, the nodes die. Can someone advise, please? Thank you.

Nathan Aw

Comment: you can run them inside `tmux` or `screen`.

Answer (score 0):

When running the nodes using the `runnodes` script, add the `--headless` flag (e.g. `build/nodes/runnodes --headless`) to start all the nodes in the main terminal.